# Prevent page from going up when out transition finishes

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, css-animations, css-transitions

When the out transition finishes, the rest of the page goes up and then down again to make space for the next image. (Look at the gif I posted)

[image: Transition bug]

this is how I implemented the transition tag:

```
      <div class="xs12 md6 lg6" >
    <transition
        v-if="heroImages[iterator] != undefined"
        mode="out-in"
        enter-active-class="animate__animated animate__fadeIn"
        leave-active-class="animate__animated animate__fadeOut"
    >
      <div v-if="iterator%2 == 1" style="display: flex;">   
        <img
          class="heroImage xs10"
          style="float:right;"
          :src="baseUrl + heroImages[iterator].url"
          alt=""
        />
      </div>
      <div v-else-if="iterator%2 == 0 && iterator != 4" style="display: flex;">
        <img
          class="heroImage xs10"
          style="float:right;"
          :src="baseUrl + heroImages[iterator].url"
          alt=""
        />
      </div>
      <div v-else style="display: flex;">
        <img
          class="heroImage xs10"
          style="float:right;"
          :src="baseUrl + heroImages[iterator].url"
          alt=""
        />
      </div>
    </transition>
  </div>
```

Iterator changes with a js function every 2 seconds. This make the image changing.

How can I avoid this graphic "glitch" between images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `v-show` instead of `v-if`   [v-show vs. v-if](https://learnvue.co/2021/05/v-if-vs-v-show-vue-conditional-rendering/) and set height on your image style.

Comment: It's faster but still the page goes up and then down again

Comment: Hey mate, have you tried to add height on your image style?